# Content-Length' bigger than max packet size in arangodb

Tags: arangodb

I'm using the latest ArangoDB of the respective release series: 3.3
Mode:Single-Server, Storage-Engine: mmfiles
On this operating system:

Windows, version: windows 10, Corei3 2.95GHz, RAM: 4GB,
I'm issuing AQL via:

[- ] web interface with this browser: Google chrome running on this OS:
[- ] arangosh
I've run db._createStatement({ query: "FOR L IN ZKWtestdata RETURN L", count: true }).execute().count()
The AQL query in question is: Find whole collection. Which i have import JSON file(count is 196,342, size: 33.05 GB).

But Its not working as I thought. Content-Length' bigger than max packet size:

[image]

How to solve this Problem?

Comment: 2018-03-02T15:37:38Z [6484] WARNING {httpclient} ignoring HTTP response with 'Content-Length' bigger than max packet size (183843177 > 134217728)
JavaScript exception in file 'c:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.3\usr\share\arangodb3\js\client\modules\@arangodb\arangosh.js' at 98,7: ArangoError 2001: ignoring HTTP response with 'Content-Length' bigger than max packet size (183843177 > 134217728)
!      throw error;
!      ^
stacktrace: ArangoError: ignoring HTTP response with 'Content-Length' bigger than max packet size (183843177 > 134217728)

Comment: Edit your question to add this information

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns the entire collection as huge dataset. The result is too large for transfer. If you want the count only:

`db._createStatement({ query: "RETURN(LENGTH(ZKWtestdata))" }).execute()`

The runtime is also easily an order of magnitude faster, as the counting is done on the server and not on the client after data transfer.